# Find files in multiple directories

Tags: linux, bash, find

I am using RHEL.  In my current folder there are sub folders. I need to find where a file is in the subfolders. The files may be in one or more.

I am using this but it iterates infinitely:

```
for f in ./{Failed,Loaded,ToLoad}; do find -name 'file';  done
```

How to get this right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The syntax of your for-loop is incorrect.

It should be:

```
for f in Failed Loaded ToLoad
do
    find "$f" -name 'file'
done
```

But you don't need a loop. It can simply be done like this:

```
find Failed Loaded ToLoad -name 'file'
```

Answer (score 12):

Try doing this :

```
find {Failed,Loaded,ToLoad} -name 'file'
```

if `{Failed,Loaded,ToLoad}` are really some dirs.

Answer (score 5):

`find` can take multiple arguments for source directory.  So, you could use:

```
find Failed Loaded ToLoad -name 'file' ...
```

You don't need a loop.  This can be handy if you want `find` to look at a subset of your subdirectories.